# jQuery dynamic resize div after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to expand a div to fit text without having to specify an exact hegiht. I tried using something like.

```
$('#div').addClass('myclass');
```

With myclass having a height:auto; but that won't work. I don't know how to get it to expand the div accordingly from an ajax call that returns text.

This is the main css class

```
.pro_input{ 
    border-top:2px solid #919191;
    border-left:1px solid #CBCBCB;
    border-right:1px solid #CBCBCB;
    border-bottom:1px solid #CBCBCB;
    width:530px;
    background-color:#F2F2F2;
    height:72px;    
 }
 .pro_attach{
     height:auto;
  }
```

I'm just trying to make the height auto after an ajax reponse. The text can be a little or a lot. So I need it to expand accordingly. I'm used the addclass to change it for other things but using it with jQuery addclass with pro_attach doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: try to remove height from your css. Or can you look in Firebug at resized element's css generated after ajax response and see if the styles are actually applied correctly (height:auto should override height:72px). Alternately just change height:72px to min-height:72px and forget about adding any other classes, ajax content will expand the element's height, but empty element will have 72px height.

Comment: thanks for the info. I tried both ways. I just realized that the div I am trying to resize is the parent and not the div the content is in. How would that be affected? Should that matter and shouldn't it work the same way?

Comment: if I understand you correctly, then you have the following: `<div id="main"><div id="ajaxHolder"></div><div>` And you want to resize main, but not ajaxHolder? In that case you can give ajaxHolder 72px height and change it to auto usising `$("#ajaxHolder").css({height: 'auto'});` when ajax arrives. Parent with no height should expand accordingly to its content.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just have to do this:
Wrap a limit div around the div you want to load text with ajax:

```
<div id="limit">
    <div id="div"> ajaxed load text </div>
</div>
```

Give the #limit div a overflow hidden:

```
#limit { position: relative; overflow: hidden; }
```

And finally, fit the #limit height to the height of the #div, at all times AFTER you load text with ajax:

```
$("#limit").css({
    height: $("#div").height()
});
```

This is the same, just animated:

```
$("#limit").animate({
    height: $("#div").height()
},600);
```

The script checks the height of the #div and give it to #limit, that's the trick.

Comment: Thanks...This works how I needed. I actually modified it a bit and took the previous height and added it like so $("#limit").css({ height:$("#div").height() + 72 });  so that it would add the previous height because it already contained content.

Comment: Very nice and elegant solution! +1

Answer (score 13):

**Assumption:** That initially, there was no content in the div. Later on, the text is added into the div.

Let's say that the id of the div is 'abc' and the height of the div when there is no content in it is 10px. then the style that I would like to give is:

```
#abc {
  min-height:10px;
  height:auto !important;
  height:10px;
}
```

Source: http://www.dustindiaz.com/min-height-fast-hack/

Comment: height:auto !important; Works!

Comment: height:auto !important: Works for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**UPD:**
I created a basic [example](http://jsbin.com/ixime3/2/edit), I am pretty sure I got it all wrong at this stage, so if you could modify it and post a link here, I would be able to be more helpful =)

**JS**

```
var testData = "Test data, Test data, Test data, Test data, Test data, Test data, Test data, Test data, Test data";


$("#btn").click(function(){
  $("#sub").html(testData);
  $("#sub").css({height: 'auto'});
});**strong text**
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  #main{
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100px;
  }
  #sub{
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 72px;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="sub">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="ajax event"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I didn't assign id of div. That was just for an example. I'll try a width and see what happens.

Comment: well you don't have to sorry =) Provide more information, some css and javascript (where you handle your ajax response) would be helpful. Also notice if ajax response contains any html tags it may break your markup.

Comment: Hi, actually the div that needs to be resized is not the main div the content is in but an outer div. Should that matter? If so how do we affect it based on the inner div's ajaxed content?

Comment: See, I can't tell for sure, because there is not enough details in the question, but if your parent div has a fixed height, your child div is not going to expand, even if its height is auto.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance Thomasz answered that worked for my issue.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is similar to one of the answers above(sv_in)

I have a div with id `abc` and has a css as follows:

```
#abc{
height:575px;
}
```

and I changed it to the following, and it worked!

```
#abc {
min-height: 575px;
height: auto;
}
```